# Save Google Sheet filter and then restore it by API

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to automatically get Google Sheets filter (BasicFilter or FilterView), clear filter, remove some rows and then apply the filter again. Is it possible ? I see that I can clear the filter using ClearBasicFilterRequest and set the filter by SetBasicFilterRequest but I cannot find any APIs to get information about the existing filter.

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: Please include the existing code you are working on.